# PHP-7 Видимо кодировка

Tags: php7

Всем привет!
Я только начал изучать PHP. 
Установил локально, у себя на машине (ubuntu 16.04) 
LAMP - Apache2, PHP-7, mysql, phpmyadmin.
Все вроде работает, кириллица отображается правильно....
HO! Я уже второй день бьюсь с такой проблемой....

```
<?php
 $word = "слово";
 echo $word[0];

 ...�
```

Соответсвенно strlen($string) - тоже не правильно работает. 
И все действия (функции) со строками в кириллице приводит к такому результату... Такие "ромбики" выдает интерпретатор в Atom, Sublime, VS-Code, phpStorm ну и веб-страница соответственно.

- Кодировка файла проверенно неоднократо!

> UTF-8 без BOM

- Добавил в htaccess

> AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

- В сам файл test.php

> header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Проверил все файлы php.ini и apache2 - везде стоит default_charset UTF-8 
Ничего не помогает!

Отчаянно прошу помощи!
Как правильно настроить кодировку рабочего окружения для PHP....
Может дело вовсе не в кодировке, а в самом PHP-7.....

Comment: Вероятнее всего, $word[0] выдает вам первый байт, в то время как кириллица в юникоде далеко не однобайтовая

Comment: **echo $word;**  ..._"слово"_  - выдает правильный результат. Есть ли возможность исправить это недоразумение...? Причем на курсе, по которому я обучаюсь, с этих проблем не наблюдается. Этот пример от туда...

Answer (score 0):

С многобайтовыми строками так нельзя.

Вам надо использовать

```
mb_substr( $word , 0, 1);
```

Расширение mbstring должно быть добавлено в php.

Comment: Это проблема php-7? В php-5.6 будет работать без mb_substr(); А как быть с примером посложнее  strlen($string); или $output .= $alfavit[$string[$i]];

Comment: Почитайте документацию php про функции mbstring